# Do I need to pay more mana to activate Outlast for other Sliver creatures in the card Enduring Sliver?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[image]

As shown in the card, you need to pay 2 additional generic mana to activate Outlast for this creature. but I was wondering about the second part that is referring to other Sliver creatures have outlast {2}. Should I pay {2} more generic mana in addition to the first {2} that were paid to activate Outlast for the creature itself? or Paying {2} generic mana for the first Outlast is enough to activate the second Outlast for other Sliver creatures?

Answer (score 7):

**No, Outlast {2} works the same for every creature that has it. If you activate Outlast on any of your creatures, it works on that creature and no other. It has no effect on or cost increase from other creatures with Outlast.**

Enduring Sliver grants each sliver you control Outlast {2} through its *static* ability. This is true as soon as, and as long as you control Enduring Sliver. You don't have to pay anything for this to take effect.

> 604.1. Static abilities do something all the time rather than being activated or triggered. They are written as statements, and they’re simply true.

Outlast itself is an *activated* ability, which means it has a cost and an effect. When you pay the cost, the ability goes on the stack, and the effect only happens if and when the ability has successfully resolved from the stack.

> 602.1. Activated abilities have a cost and an effect. They are written as “[Cost]: [Effect.] [Activation instructions (if any).]”

The mana cost to activate Outlast is not somehow cumulative, and activating one has no influence on others. Enduring Sliver's first ability grants "Outlast {2}" only to itself, the object represented by the card. What Outlast {2} means is briefly explained in the italicized reminder text in parentheses.

The second line grants Outlast {2} to all *other* Sliver creatures you control. On those creatures it works exactly the same as on Enduring Sliver itself: You pay {2} and tap the creature to put a +1/+1 counter on exactly that creature.

Assuming you control exactly one Enduring Sliver, each Sliver you control has exactly one instance of Outlast among their abilities, and they function entirely independent of each other.

Comment: If you have two Enduring Slivers, then every sliver you control has two identical outlast abilities. This is functionally identical to having one.

Comment: So tapping & paying {2} generic mana to activate Outlast 2 will grant it to Enduring Sliver & all other Sliver creatures. I can do this as much as I want (once every turn). Whenever my turn comes, I can tap Enduring Sliver then pay {2} mana to put a +1/+1 counter on Enduring Sliver and every other Sliver creature by just that? or is it that when I tap and pay {2} for Outlast {2} in Enduring Sliver [since after that moment every other Sliver creature will have outlast {2}] the other Sliver creature that I want to increase its P/T I have to tap it and pay another {2} for me to put for it +1/+1??

Comment: As soon as, and as long as Enduring Sliver is on the battlefield, each sliver you control has its own instance of Outlast 2 automatically as one of its abilities. To actually use (activate) Outlast, you have to pay 2 and tap the creature you want to use it on. Only the sliver you activate it for gets the counter.

Answer (score 1):

As long as Enduring Sliver is on the battlefield, you can act as if every sliver you control has "You may pay 2 and tap this creature to give this creature a +1/+1 counter" in its text box. Paying 2 and tapping a sliver only gives that sliver a +1/+1 counter. It does not affect any of the other slivers. You cannot pay 4 and tap one sliver to give +1/+1 counters to two slivers. To give +1/+1 to two slivers, you have to pay 4 and tap both slivers.